# ExtJs layout, timezone to be shown next to date time field

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an requirement to show date and time fields and which timezone exist as a text next to those fields as shown in the link

date range with datetime fields
[image]

Can someone help how to achieve the above fields using **Ext3 or Ext4**?

Comment: Have you already tried to do something? May you show your code?

Comment: It is an customized application, just the date and time fields already available was unable to add "From' and 'To' and the timezone should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

just get the timezone offset and then get the timezone that matches.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

        Ext.Msg.show({
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
            title: 'Timezone Offset',
            message: `the current timezone offset is: ${offset}`
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Working on timezone placement will check with this and I had added the field labels by using a common code in my application.